# Netbeans: Cannot use custom jComponent (not in classpath?)

Tags: netbeans, classpath, java

I have troubles understanding what to specifically add to the classpath, or what this error means.

My setup is this in Netbeans:

```
Package
  --> src
        --> FooMainApplet.java
        --> FooMainAppletMyJcomponent.java
```

The Jcomponent class simply extends jComponent in which I believe is valid, and has a few helper methods (i.e. getPreferredSize()  and alike)

I can add this new component manually, with the getContainer().add() method however it is not visualized on the designer, even if I use the second .add() parameter and define the layout styles as the designer would normally.

When I try to add it as a component (i.e. dragging the .java file on the the form, or manually adding it as a .jar file in the pallette manager, or even placing it in what I assume are class path jar's) it comes up with the following error:

```
Cannot load component class <projectname>.<customcomponentsname> from JAR file: <some path to dist>/<mainprojectjar>.jar.
The class must be compiled and must be on the classpath of the project to which this form belongs.
```

And above it in the IDE log it complains about an unsupported major.minor versions in my custom component's class `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

I am sure this is related to me adding the .jar in dist/ rather than what I had done before (simple dragging of the .java file as I have read could work) however they both lead to it saying it is not compiled or in the class path, even though I do add the .jar in to the project's library section and that seems all I can do.

Do you know what the issue is, and how to work around this? Do I need to compile the custom component as a completely separate .jar (separate from my main applet class) in order to use it in the designer (even though it lets me select which class to use)?

My project is built each save, and still after a clean make it still issues this error as well.

I am using Netbeans 7 and JDK 1.7 I believe

Answer (score 0):

Completing a clean and build should resolve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't.